# How to make a new entry if there is more than one array with couchbase query?

Tags: couchbase, sql++

> **Now, I am getting data like this.**

```
{
 "data": {
  "name": "entertainment",
  "carriers": [111,222,333]
 }
}
```

> **but i want new entry/record if carriers are more than one like this**

```
{
 "data": {
  "name": "entertainment",
  "carriers": 111
  }
},
{
 "data": {
  "name": "entertainment",
  "carriers": 222
  }
},
{
 "data": {
  "name": "entertainment",
  "carriers": 333
 }
}
```

> **How can i achieve data like this?**

Answer (score 0):

Use the [NEST clause](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/from.html#story-h2-6)

```
SELECT * FROM bucket
NEST bucket.carriers
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query

```
from orders o unnest o.carriers a select {"carriers":a, "name":o.name } as data;
```

This should give you the output you desire -

```
[
 {
  "data": {
  "carriers": 111,
  "name": "entertainment"
 }
},
{
  "data": {
  "carriers": 222,
  "name": "entertainment"
 }
},
{
"data": {
  "carriers": 333,
  "name": "entertainment"
}
}
]
```

This query assumes the following -
bucket name - orders
sample document -

```
{
  "name": "entertainment",
  "carriers": [
    111,
    222,
    333
  ]
}
```